# How to fix a broken plugin (it cannot import name NavigationToolbar2QTAgg)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, profile, hec-ras

I want to use the the pluging ProfileFromPoints but I am getting an error saying `cannot import name NavigationToolbar2QTAgg`. The solution seems to link with an old library name as mentioned here: https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/issues/2

[image]

Can I amend it without wayting for the bug fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proceeded with the plugin installation without caring about the warning. Then I wnet to the pluging directory and I manually edited the python file `profileFromPoints_dialog.py`

In the line 30 I changed:

```
 39# from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
```

to

```
 39# from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
```

Then, I restarted QGIS and I needed to load the plugin.